# Que esta fallando?

Tags: python

Estaba intentando hacer un programa sencillo para ir aprendiendo, y esta fallando esto:

```
Selecciona tu asignatura optativa
    -------------------------------------------------
    {1: 'Informatica', 2: 'Ofimatica', 3: 'Exomatica', 4: 'Tracomatica'}
    Introduce el numero de tu asignatura deseada.2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "wawawa.py", line 15, in <module>
        SelectorAsignatura(Asignatura)
      File "wawawa.py", line 10, in SelectorAsignatura
        if AsignaturasOptativas.index("id")==True:
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

    ***Repl Closed***
```

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
   AsignaturasOptativas={1:"Informatica", 2:"Ofimatica", 3:"Exomatica", 4:"Tracomatica"}

print("Selecciona tu asignatura optativa")
print("-------------------------------------------------")
print(AsignaturasOptativas)

Asignatura=input("Introduce el numero de tu asignatura deseada.")

def SelectorAsignatura(id):
    if AsignaturasOptativas.index("id")==True:
        print(AsignaturasOptativas.values(id))
    elif AsignaturasOptativas.index("id")==False:
        print("La asignatura no existe")

SelectorAsignatura(Asignatura)
```

Que he puesto mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, sucede que tienes varios problemas, index es la manera de llamar a diccionarios, para obtener el valor de un diccionario usa AsignaturasOptativas .get(indice, 'valor a retornar si no existe'), o usar AsignaturasOptativas[id]

por ejemplo

```
def SelectorAsignatura(id):
    print (AsignaturasOptativas.get(id, "La asignatura no existe")
```

En caso de usar get en un diccionario y no expecificar el valor a esperar, en caso de que no exista el indice especificado devolvera None

Ejemplo

```
valor = AsignaturasOptativas.get(id)
if valor is None:
    print("La asignatura no existe")
else:
    print(AsignaturasOptativas[id])
```

Lo que quieres hacer, es comprobar que la clave existe en el diccionario, lo harias asi, con in:

```
if id in AsignaturasOptativas:
        print(AsignaturasOptativas.values(id))
elif id not in AsignaturasOptativas:
        print("La asignatura no existe")
```